# Partitions are gone after restart of virtual machine

Tags: linux

I created 3 volumes on a newly added disk. Being new to this kind of operations, I might have written some bad commands while doing this. But in the end, everything was well. Then I restarted the virtual machine.

Now, the volumes are gone, the partition gone too, the volume group is not present in /dev/ (lsblk and fdisk -l doesn't show them):

But, when I try creating them again, Linux complains that they already exists:

> A volume group called vg1 already exists.
>
> Logical volume "tenvol" already exists in volume group "vg1"

Is there any way I could get them back or at least make Linux let me create them again?
The OS is Red Hat Linux 6.5

EDIT:

```
[root@fayedb ~]# cat /proc/partitions

major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0   20971520 sda

   8        1     204800 sda1

   8        2   20765696 sda2

   8       16  209715200 sdb

   8       17  209712478 sdb1

 253        0    2097152 dm-0

 253        1    2097152 dm-1

 253        2    5242880 dm-2

 253        3    1048576 dm-3

 253        4    2097152 dm-4

 253        5    2097152 dm-5
```

pvscan shows ar error:

```
[root@fayedb ~]# pvscan

  Couldn't find device with uuid PSeNdD-Plks-QdMf-OjWm-A8td-NjHU-lO1Pmi.

  PV /dev/sdb1        VG vg1    lvm2 [200.00 GiB / 0    free]

  PV /dev/sda2        VG vg00   lvm2 [19.80 GiB / 5.80 GiB free]

  PV unknown device   VG vg00   lvm2 [200.00 GiB / 200.00 GiB free]

  Total: 3 [419.79 GiB] / in use: 3 [419.79 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

Comment: They probably aren't mounted...

Comment: I can't mount them because the volume group is gone... The /dev/vg1 folder doesn't exist anymore, so I can't use the mount command

Comment: Trying doing `cat /proc/partitions` then `pvscan` and report the results

Comment: Now try `vgcfgrestore vg1` or `vgcfgrestore vg00`

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) After vgcfgrestore vg1 I had to restart the virtual machine, but now everything is there again. I'm not sure if vgcfgrestore or the restart itself solved the problem. I believe I can't choose a comment as the correct answer, but thanks again and if you want you can add it as an aswer and I will surely accept it :)

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! actually both the restore and the reboot are responsible for solving the issue. A straight reboot without a restore is often fine, although if something is corrupted it could potentially make matters worse, and in some cases I think doing a restore then rebooting is sometimes safer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the partitions are still there, it's just a matter of verifying:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

returns the list of partitions.

```
pvscan
```

will scan all supported LVM block devices in the system for physical volumes. Depending on the result of that last command, you might see a message similar to:

```
Couldn't find device with uuid (PSeNdD-Plks-QdMf-OjWm-A8td-NjHU-lO1Pmi)
```

You can either reboot and hope that `/etc/init.d/boot.lvm` start script will scan and activate the volume group at boot time, or you can do a restore and reboot:

```
vgcfgrestore <volume group>
```

If all went good (meaning your meta data was still intact) things should be restored.